# Privacy violation for movies, but not for photos when using UIImagePickerController in iOS 10

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios10, privacy

I have an app that can take photos and movies using an `UIImagePickerController`.
I have set `NSCameraUsageDescription` in `Info.plist` (actually, localized in `InfoPlist.strings`).

When the app was launched and I tried to take a photo, I was asked for permission, which I granted. Now, **I can take photos without problems**.

However, **when I try to take a movie, the app crashes always due to a privacy violation** (see stack trace below).
This crash happens sometimes before the camera interface is presented, and sometime afterwards (see screenshot below).

I don’t think it has anything to do with the way I present the camera interface, but here is the code anyway:

```
+ (void)takePhotoOrMovie:(CFStringRef)mediaType inViewController:(UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> *)viewController 
{
    UIImagePickerController *takePhotoOrMovieController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    takePhotoOrMovieController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    NSString *mediaTypePhotoOrMovie = (__bridge NSString *)mediaType;
    takePhotoOrMovieController.mediaTypes = @[mediaTypePhotoOrMovie];
    takePhotoOrMovieController.allowsEditing = YES; // Enables the controls for editing
    takePhotoOrMovieController.delegate = viewController;
    [viewController presentViewController:takePhotoOrMovieController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The parameter `mediaType` is `kUTTypeImage` for photo and `kUTTypeMovie` for movie.

Any idea what is wrong and how to correct it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` key also.